# Web scraping Element filled via JavaScript

Tags: web-scraping

Here is the link in question: https://bittrex.com/Market/Index?MarketName=BTC-DASH

I would like to be able to scrape the data (or find the underlying REST API method) contained in the "Timeline" element.

I've used Chrome to "Inspect element" and look at network sources, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: The "timeline" element is right there when you use the "Inspect element" menu entry in Chromium...

Comment: Yes, I know how to find it. I'm looking for the data inside the "Timeline" element. The chart data.

Comment: Hm, in your question you claim you _can't seem to find it_... Apart from that: what is the problem here, it is right there! just below that tab definition! Could it be that you don't really know what you are looking for? Don't get me wrong, I am not trying to be impolite! Just trying to find out what your question actually is!

Comment: I can't seem to find the data that's in the chart labeled "Timeline." I can find the element fine, but I just can't find the data or the data source that's contained in it.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://ibin.co/23dffgRxHvQS Two areas in the console marked in red: 1. the tab and 2. the active content area. Main elements of the content area are two svgs, the second one is of interest for you.